# Are there any famous people who died from cancer before 1800?

Tags: middle-ages, ancient-history, early-modern, disease, famous-people

[Cancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cancer) was described by the ancient Egyptians by 1600 BC and, much later, by Hippocrates and then [Celsus during the early empire](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/cncr.20198). Cases were diagnosed but there is no mention of people who were famous.

More recently, science has provided [proof of cancer in ancient Egypt](https://www.curetoday.com/articles/ancient-history-two-mummies-discovered-with-cancer). Several articles (for example, [here](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/12/28/health/28cancer.html) and [here](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/07/oldest-human-cancer-disease-origins-tumor-fossil-science/) and [here](https://www.canaryfoundation.org/2012/08/13/how-long-have-we-been-plagued-by-cancer/) also say that cancer was less common than it is now.

**Are there any famous people who died from cancer before 1800?**

***Famous*** - widely-known in their own time (for example, rulers of independent states, popes, writers). On this basis, [Cicero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicero), [Shakespeare](https://www.britishcouncil.org/voices-magazine/was-shakespeare-popular-his-own-time-he-now) and [Chaucer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoffrey_Chaucer) would be included but [not Jane Austen](https://www.biography.com/people/jane-austen-9192819).

Three or four examples, each from a different historical period and different geographical area would be appreciated.

Also, examples should be where we are certain that person died of cancer by modern scientists examining remains. Cases where there is consensus among historians and scientists would also be acceptable. Cases which are only possible or probable are **not** acceptable (for example, [Edward I and Mary I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monarchs_of_the_British_Isles_by_cause_of_death)

Comment: What has your initial research shown you so far?

Comment: How can we revise this question for reopening?  Can anyone suggest a rewrite?

Comment: General and President U. S. Grant died of throat cancer in 1885.

Comment: Heinrich Hertz, who discovered radio waves, died of cancer.

Comment: Clerk-Maxwell, who completed the theory of electrodynamics, died of cancer.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I think it can be revised for reopening but how far is it acceptable to go in the edit? For a start, the date needs to be pushed further back, perhaps to before the industrial revolution. Not sure on the 'etiquette' here...

Comment: I've edited this to try to bring it on-topic. The OP does not appear to have visited the site since posting but I think the edit mostly respects the original intent. If anyone thinks they can improve it, or you think the time-frame or 'famous' needs further refinement, please feel free to make any such improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Hatshepsut**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatshepsut), 18th dynasty female pharaoh who ruled circa 1478–1458 BC, had bone cancer. Her identity and the diagnosis has been [confirmed by scientific research](https://nilefm.com/digest/article/2388/research-shows-ancient-egyptian-queen-hatshepsut-died-of-cancer).

[**Ferdinand I of Naples**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_I_of_Naples), reigned 1458-94. According to Wikipedia,

> The cause of his death was determined in 2006 to have been colorectal
>   cancer (mucinous adenocarcinoma type with mutation in the KRas gene),
>   by examination of his mummy.

**Anne of Austria** (1601-1666) [died of breast cancer](https://jbuon.com/pdfs/10-2/JBUON-10-2-285.pdf). As the wife of [Louis XIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XIII_of_France) of France, she was Queen Consort of France (1615-43). From 1643 to 1651 she was regent during the minority of [Louis XIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_XIV_of_France).

[**Mary Ball Washington**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Ball_Washington#Death) (1708-89), mother of [George Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington), died of breast cancer. An account of her treatment and last days [can be found here](https://www.mountvernon.org/blog/2018/10/mary-ball-washingtons-battle-with-breast-cancer).